# How to make Question visible on top in stack overflow

Tags: discussion, support

I have added One question before One day. But  I still not get answer for that question.
Now people are not looking at this question. So I just want to make it visible on newest question list at top.

Is anybody know how to do this thing?

Or any other solution will also appreciate.

Comment: [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Comment: I know about bounty, but I have added question before a day

Comment: You can edit if you have anything to fix or add. Otherwise just wait and when time comes, place a bounty.

Comment: Ask yourself if your question is actually answerable. Look at [this checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). If your question cannot be improved anymore, stick a bounty on it.

Comment: I don't get it. I see you have answers for both questions you asked. Can you provide a link to the question you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your question with *some updates that you have tried after adding the question* and if you have enough reputation for bounty, then you can add it to your question.

Since you mentioned you waited a day, so I'm sure you must have tried multiple attempts.  Add those information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) or you can rephrase / retag the question. Active (edited) questions appear higher [in these lists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active).